# mongodb 3.2.7 sorting not using compound index

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm using mongodb 3.2.7, docs like:

```
{
    "finished" : true,
    "buildNo": 1,
    "tryTimes" : 1,
    "createdTime" : ISODate("2019-05-16T19:00:50.604+08:00"),
    "modifiedTime" : ISODate("2019-12-27T18:33:25.682+08:00"),
}
```

I created my index using:

```
db.getCollection('builds').createIndex({"createdTime": 1})
db.getCollection('builds').createIndex({"tryTimes": 1, "createdTime": -1})
```

and my query is :

```
db.getCollection('builds').find({
"createdTime": {$lte: new Date("2020-04-15T00:00:00.000Z"), $gte: new Date("2020-04-01T00:00:00.000Z")},
"buildNo": 1, 
"finished": {$ne: true}
})
.sort({"tryTimes": 1, "createdTime": -1})
.limit(200)
```

But this query doesn't use the index I created before. the explain() output:

```
{
"queryPlanner" : {
    "plannerVersion" : 1,
    "namespace" : "builds",
    "indexFilterSet" : false,
    "parsedQuery" : {
        "$and" : [ 
            {
                "buildNo" : {
                    "$eq" : 1.0
                }
            }, 
            {
                "createdTime" : {
                    "$lte" : ISODate("2020-04-15T08:00:00.000+08:00")
                }
            }, 
            {
                "createdTime" : {
                    "$gte" : ISODate("2020-04-01T08:00:00.000+08:00")
                }
            }, 
            {
                "$not" : {
                    "finished" : {
                        "$eq" : true
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "winningPlan" : {
        "stage" : "SORT",
        "sortPattern" : {
            "tryTimes" : 1.0,
            "createdTime" : -1.0
        },
        "limitAmount" : 200,
        "inputStage" : {
            "stage" : "SORT_KEY_GENERATOR",
            "inputStage" : {
                "stage" : "FETCH",
                "filter" : {
                    "$and" : [ 
                        {
                            "buildNo" : {
                                "$eq" : 1.0
                            }
                        }, 
                        {
                            "$not" : {
                                "finished" : {
                                    "$eq" : true
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "inputStage" : {
                    "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                    "keyPattern" : {
                        "createdTime" : 1.0
                    },
                    "indexName" : "createdTime_1",
                    "isMultiKey" : false,
                    "isUnique" : false,
                    "isSparse" : false,
                    "isPartial" : false,
                    "indexVersion" : 1,
                    "direction" : "forward",
                    "indexBounds" : {
                        "createdTime" : [ 
                            "[new Date(1585699200000), new Date(1586908800000)]"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "rejectedPlans" : [ 
        {
            "stage" : "LIMIT",
            "limitAmount" : 200,
            "inputStage" : {
                "stage" : "FETCH",
                "filter" : {
                    "$and" : [ 
                        {
                            "buildNo" : {
                                "$eq" : 1.0
                            }
                        }, 
                        {
                            "createdTime" : {
                                "$lte" : ISODate("2020-04-15T08:00:00.000+08:00")
                            }
                        }, 
                        {
                            "createdTime" : {
                                "$gte" : ISODate("2020-04-01T08:00:00.000+08:00")
                            }
                        }, 
                        {
                            "$not" : {
                                "finished" : {
                                    "$eq" : true
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "inputStage" : {
                    "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                    "keyPattern" : {
                        "tryTimes" : 1.0,
                        "createdTime" : -1.0
                    },
                    "indexName" : "tryTimes_1_createdTime_-1",
                    "isMultiKey" : false,
                    "isUnique" : false,
                    "isSparse" : false,
                    "isPartial" : false,
                    "indexVersion" : 1,
                    "direction" : "forward",
                    "indexBounds" : {
                        "tryTimes" : [ 
                            "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
                        ],
                        "createdTime" : [ 
                            "[MaxKey, MinKey]"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ]
},
"executionStats" : {
    "executionSuccess" : true,
    "nReturned" : 200,
    "executionTimeMillis" : 352,
    "totalKeysExamined" : 48256,
    "totalDocsExamined" : 48256,
    "executionStages" : {
        "stage" : "SORT",
        "nReturned" : 200,
        "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 200,
        "works" : 48459,
        "advanced" : 200,
        "needTime" : 48258,
        "needYield" : 0,
        "saveState" : 757,
        "restoreState" : 757,
        "isEOF" : 1,
        "invalidates" : 0,
        "sortPattern" : {
            "tryTimes" : 1.0,
            "createdTime" : -1.0
        },
        "memUsage" : 198706,
        "memLimit" : 33554432,
        "limitAmount" : 200,
        "inputStage" : {
            "stage" : "SORT_KEY_GENERATOR",
            "nReturned" : 0,
            "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 180,
            "works" : 48258,
            "advanced" : 0,
            "needTime" : 24539,
            "needYield" : 0,
            "saveState" : 757,
            "restoreState" : 757,
            "isEOF" : 1,
            "invalidates" : 0,
            "inputStage" : {
                "stage" : "FETCH",
                "filter" : {
                    "$and" : [ 
                        {
                            "buildNo" : {
                                "$eq" : 1.0
                            }
                        }, 
                        {
                            "$not" : {
                                "finished" : {
                                    "$eq" : true
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "nReturned" : 23718,
                "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 160,
                "works" : 48257,
                "advanced" : 23718,
                "needTime" : 24538,
                "needYield" : 0,
                "saveState" : 757,
                "restoreState" : 757,
                "isEOF" : 1,
                "invalidates" : 0,
                "docsExamined" : 48256,
                "alreadyHasObj" : 0,
                "inputStage" : {
                    "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                    "nReturned" : 48256,
                    "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 20,
                    "works" : 48257,
                    "advanced" : 48256,
                    "needTime" : 0,
                    "needYield" : 0,
                    "saveState" : 757,
                    "restoreState" : 757,
                    "isEOF" : 1,
                    "invalidates" : 0,
                    "keyPattern" : {
                        "createdTime" : 1.0
                    },
                    "indexName" : "createdTime_1",
                    "isMultiKey" : false,
                    "isUnique" : false,
                    "isSparse" : false,
                    "isPartial" : false,
                    "indexVersion" : 1,
                    "direction" : "forward",
                    "indexBounds" : {
                        "createdTime" : [ 
                            "[new Date(1585699200000), new Date(1586908800000)]"
                        ]
                    },
                    "keysExamined" : 48256,
                    "dupsTested" : 0,
                    "dupsDropped" : 0,
                    "seenInvalidated" : 0
                }
            }
        }
    }
},
"serverInfo" : {
    "host" : "...",
    "port" : 9999,
    "version" : "3.2.7",
    "gitVersion" : "4249c1d2b5999ebbf1fdf3bc0e0e3b3ff5c0aaf2"
},
"ok" : 1.0}
```

even if I try to simplify the query to

```
db.getCollection('builds')
.find({ "buildNo": 1,  "finished": true })
.sort({"tryTimes": 1, "createdTime": -1})
.limit(200)
```

, the index still doesn't work.

The wierd things is: I use the same index and query on another mongondb ver. 3.4.14.3. The index works...

Any ideas is welcomed and appreciated.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a query can be satisfied by multiple indexes (satisfied is used losely as Mongo actually chooses all possibly relevant indexes) defined in the collection, MongoDB will then test all the applicable indexes in parallel (meaning Mongo's performs a "race"). The first index that can returns 101 results will be selected by the query planner.

Meaning that for that certain query your using the "wrong" index wins.

What can you do?:

You can use [$hint](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/meta/hint/), hint basically forces Mongo to use a specific index, however Mongo this is not recommended because if changes occur Mongo will not adapt to those.

Like so:

```
db.getCollection('builds')
.find({ "buildNo": 1,  "finished": true })
.sort({"tryTimes": 1, "createdTime": -1})
.limit(200)
.hint({tryTimes: 1, createdTime: -1})
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Tom. That really helps. I think i'll just let mongo decide which index to use.

Comment: Another question: how can we tell that it's  "the 'wrong' index wins" or  is just the index we created is not appropriate.

Comment: You don't really know if the index you created is appropriate or not (sometimes it's pretty obvious but sometimes testing is required to find the optimal one). Also there's no actual way of knowing whats the "right" or "wrong" index for a query code wise, this is why Mongo choose their race method to do so. the rule of thumb i use is creating tailored indexes for my needs (usually multiple fields compound indexes) and if i suddenly get bad unexpected performance it's almost always due to Mongo utilising the wrong index.