# mongo query does not trigger compound index

Tags: mongodb, indexing, mongodb-query, compound-index

I've got hundreds of thousands of documents like this :

```
    {
  "field_id" : "abcd",
  "aField" : 0,
  "parentList": [
      {
        "field": "value1",
        "list": ["element1,element2"]
      }
      , 
      {
        "field": "value2",
        "list": ["element1, element3"]
      }
  ]
}
```

(this is an oversemplified version of a much bigger document in my db, containing more fields. The DB contains millions of documents).
Here's the filter that I want to use for a count execution:

```
{ 'parentList.0.list': 
         { '$in': 
            [ 'element1',
              'element2',
              'element3',
              'element4' 
              ] 
            },
        aField: { '$ne': 1 },
        field_id: { '$in': [ 'abcd' ] } 
}
```

What I'm trying to do is to create an index like this:

```
{"field_id" : 1, "parentList.list" :1, "aField" : 1}
```

and let the query use it. But mongo is actually ignoring it. Instead, mongo is using another index, which is

```
{"field_id":1, "anotherField":1}
```

The execution stats shows this staging:

1. IXSCAN on {"field_id":1, "anotherField":1} index, yielding 500k keysExamined, which are the 500k documents that have field_id = 'abcd'
2. FETCH the rest of the filter, returning 20k as count

Of course, if mongo used the correct index, I'd expect it to retrieve already the 20k documents from the IXSCAN, or at least a number closer to that.

I just can't understand why mongo is not using that index. I've also tried to change the order of the fields in the index, with no success.
I'm using Mongo 4.4.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED**

So this was actually easy to solve. MongoDB Compass wouldn't let me create an index on a certain position of array (in this case parentList.0.list), because when I tried to insert it, it automatically replaced it with parentList.list.
Eventually, I found out that an index on a certain position of an array is actually doable, if done in the shell. So I created the index on parentList.0.list and the index worked fine.
That's it. Hope this helps other people too.

Answer (score 0):

Mongo can sometimes uses the wrong index, I recommend you read my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61246308/10770370) which explains why this could happen.

In order to "fix" the behavior you should use [$hint](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/meta/hint/), it will force Mongo to use the specific index you specify.

Comment: Actually, if I'll use hint, it even returns MORE keysExamined than before. Like 520k instead of 500k. So weird

Comment: So it seems Mongo is selecting the "best" existing index for the job. I can recommend some changes to increase performance if you'd like

Answer (score 0):

Does this index

```
{"field_id":1, "anotherField":1}
```

work for most queries against your db?

In my experience, MongoDB will often choose a very generic index even if sometimes a more specific index is better. I fixed this by making the indexes more specific to their uses (and removing "catch-all" indexes). I don't know whether this applies to your use case because the reasoning for the chosen index isn't known.